# XPath Extract Specific Text From A Nested Div

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, extract, text-extraction

I'm trying to get the list of URL's that contains "2020" from a nested div using Screaming Frog. What is the XPath I should use? I'm not good at XPath. I have tried a few but none worked.

[I’m trying to extract text from this Div #image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bY7K.png)

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `//div[@class='content hotel-list']` to select the div for starters.

Comment: @zx485, thanks for your reply. I know how to select a div but I don't know how to combine it with `contains(text()`. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Try Either of `XPATH`.

**XPATH1**:

```
//div[@class='content hotel-list' and contains(., 'Erken Rezervasyon 2020')]
```

**XPATH2**:

```
//div[@class='content hotel-list'][.//h2[text()='Erken Rezervasyon 2020']]
```

Comment: If this resolved to question please mark this as accepted answer.check how you can do that https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers